# Extending ngOptions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-options

Hey I am trying to write a directive to extend ngOptions. I'm fairly new to angular so if you see anything that can be improved on let me know.

So I want to write a directive that will let me add attributes to the options generated by ngOption. I've created a simple directive that will add a title, class or whatever attribute I define to the options. This works but I feel it's a little messy. Keep in mind that not all the error handling is present. This is still a prototype.

Here's my directive

```
.directive('ngOptionsExt', function($parse) {
  //Simplified ng-options regex still messy
  var regex = /^\s*([\s\S]+?)?\sfor\s+([\$\w][\$\w]*)\s+in\s+([\s\S]+?)(?:\s+track\s+by\s+([\s\S]+?))$/;
  return {
    require: 'select',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

      var match = attrs.ngOptionsExt.match(regex);

      if (match) {
        var map = match[1],
          option = match[2],
          optionSource = match[3],
          track = match[4] || false,
          getOptionsAttrs = $parse(map);

        scope.$watchCollection(optionSource, function(items) {

          angular.forEach(items, function(item, index) {
            var attributes = getOptionsAttrs(item);

            if (track)
              option = elem.find('option[' + track + '="' + item[track] + '"]');
            else
              option = elem.find('option[value' + index + ']');

            angular.forEach(attributes, function(val, attrName) {
              angular.element(option).attr(attrName, val);
            });

          });
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

Usage:

```
ng-options-ext="{title: label, class: label} for option in options track by label"
```

Where `options` is the same model used for ngOptions. The track by is simply used to find the options by label (Not sure if that's the right way either) to avoid relying on an index to add the attributes.

The directive above will add a title and a class that will have the same value as the label of the option element.

Have you guys ever had to write something similar and have any ideas on how to improve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you write an indpendent directive that simply finds the 'option' elements and appends the attributes and values that you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngRepeat on `<option>` inside `<select>`.

```
<select ng-model="value" ng-change="change()">
  <option ng-repeat="element in elements " value="{{element.value}}" 
        data-custom-attribute="...">{{element.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: that is not the same thing as ng-options

Comment: Yes, but, it is more simple then creating another ngOptions extention  directive, and he can also wrappe this html in another directive and replace it, for reuse  ...

Comment: One of the advantages of ngOptions is that it allows you to select an object but display a label... pretty useful.

Comment: aside from performance (ng repeat create a scope for every element so more memory), what you said can be done, in my exemple.

Comment: Although I do agree that this solution is simpler. My particular scenario is limited to using ngOptions.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I ended up with something like this. Seems works well and looks cleaner than what I had before. @o4ohel, I went ahead and simply looped over the options like you've mentioned. Then mapped the attributes to the option source.

```
.directive('ngOptionsAttr', function ($parse) {
    return {
        require: 'select',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var match = attrs.ngOptionsAttr.split(' for '),
                map = match[0],
                src = match[1],
                getOptionsAttrs = $parse(map);
            scope.$watchCollection(src, function() {
                angular.forEach(elem.find("option"), function (option) {
                    angular.forEach(getOptionsAttrs(option), function(val, name) {
                        angular.element(option).attr(name, val);
                    });
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Usage:

```
ng-options-attr="{title: label} for options"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and solved it by just overriding the $render function and used lodash to loop through the options to set my attributes,

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes, modelCtrl){
    modelCtrl.$render = function() {
        var select = element.find(select);
        _.each(select.children(), function(option) {
            //set attributes here
        }
    }
}
```

The only requirement here is to have require: 'ngModel' in your directive definition.